# What was the reasoning behind ClojureScript not needing Clojure's defstruct?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

`defstruct` is not supported in ClojureScript - it would appear to be by design. Now it may be that this is effectively a deprecated part of the Clojure language, and the designers of ClojureScript were just hoping everyone had moved on. (But this is my speculation).

My question is: **What was the reasoning behind ClojureScript not needing Clojure's defstruct?**

Comment: It *is* effectively deprecated in the language, in favor of `defrecord`: [defstruct](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/defstruct).  We are supposed to move on in (JVM-based) Clojure.  I would expect Clojurescript to be the same.

Comment: Great - add that as an answer with a reference and I'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`defstruct` *is* effectively deprecated in the language, in favor of `defrecord`.  We are supposed to move on in (JVM-based) Clojure, so I would expect Clojurescript to be the same.  See the following:

[Clojure: data structures](http://clojure.org/data_structures): "Note: Most uses of StructMaps would now be better served by records."

[ClojureDocs: defstruct](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/defstruct) comment by steveminer: "Structs are obsolete. Use records instead. See defrecord."

The forthcoming *The Joy of Clojure*, 2nd ed. (prerelease V9 edition) by Fogus and Houser says "With the advent of `defrecord`, the need for structs has been nearly eliminated, and therefore structs aren’t covered in this book." (p. 322)

Also note that *Programming Clojure*, 2nd ed. by Halloway and Bedra covers `defrecord` but not `defstruct` (although there are some passing mentions of structures--maybe accidentally left from the 1st ed.).

I guess all the cool people are using `defrecord` these days. :-)

[Alex Miller's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4576143/1455243) to "Where should I use defrecord in clojure?" has a nice discussion of advantages (and disadvantages) of `defrecord`, although he's not, primarily, comparing it with `defstruct`.

Comment: Also, in JS the distinction between objects (as in instances of a class) and free-form hashmaps is blurred. Except for optimisation purposes, I guess.