# Falsy return value using contains? function

Tags: clojure

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here:

```
(defstruct prefix :a :b :c :d :e)

(def peN (struct prefix "pen" "pe" "pem" "peng" "peny"))

(contains? peN "pen") ;=> false
```

I expect it to return true. Perhaps I am not using contains? correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, [`defstruct` is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23148768/5044950); you should use [`defrecord`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/defrecord) instead:

```
(defrecord Prefix [a b c d e])

(def pen (->Prefix "pen" "pe" "pem" "peng" "peny"))

(contains? pen "pen") ;=> false
```

Now, why does this call to `contains?` return `false`? Well, records are basically just maps with a bit of extra functionality (that is irrelevant in this case), so this is equivalent to

```
(def pen {:a "pen" :b "pe" :c "pem" :d "peng" :e "peny"})

(contains? pen "pen") ;=> false
```

Now, if we look at the docstring of [`contains?`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/contains_q), we can find our answer:

> Returns true if key is present in the given collection, otherwise returns false.

In this case, the set of keys in our collection is

```
(keys pen) ;=> (:a :b :c :d :e)
```

What we really want is to see whether `"pen"` is contained in the set of *values* in `pen`, like so:

```
(contains? (set (vals pen)) "pen") ;=> true
```

But this begs the question: why don't you just make `pen` a set in the first place?

```
(def pen #{"pen" "pe" "pem" "peng" "peny"})

(contains? pen "pen") ;=> true
```

Comment: I have a few different kinds of prefixes. Would a set make more sense?

Comment: @MahmudAdam I'm not sure I understand. Could you clarify what you mean by "I have a few different kinds of prefixes"?

Comment: I created a generic map called prefix because I had more than one kind of prefix to work with. The language I am working with has  five forms of the pen prefix and five different forms of a men prefix. So I thought that having a general map structure for prefixes was the way to go so I could create different maps based on the same prefix structure.

Comment: @MahmudAdam A map may perhaps be better in that case; I'd probably use a map over a record, at least. Since your keys were simply `:a`, `:b`, `:c`, etc., I assumed that they weren't significant.

Answer (score 1):

[`contains?`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/contains_q) checks for keys, not values.  This is one way to find out if your map contains that value:

```
(some #(= "pen" %)(vals peN))
```

Comment: What function would I use to check values?