# Clojure : Are struct or create-struct deprecated?

Tags: clojure

Is struct or create-struct deprecated?. 
I´ve read here that I should use defrecord instead:
https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/struct

Thanks
R.

Comment: This doesn’t seem like a useful question and answer. If you’re just interested in whether `struct` etc. are deprecated in Clojure, anyone can answer that by looking at the documentation. More informative answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/23148768 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/4576143

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Clojure v1.8 API](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/api-index.html) documenatation the struct and create-struct are not deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

According to ["Why have both deftype and defrecord?"](https://clojure.org/reference/datatypes#_why_have_both_deftype_and_defrecord), ...

> Overall, records will be better than structmaps for all
>   information-bearing purposes, and you should move such structmaps to
>   defrecord. It is unlikely much code was trying to use structmaps for
>   programming constructs, but if so, you will find deftype much more
>   suitable.

Comment: [Alex Miller's thorough answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4576143), referred to  in a comment on the question, is much better than this. It starts *I consider structs to be effectively deprecated so I don't use them at all*.